# split generic list

Tags: linq, generics, list, lambda

I need to split a list into two equal lists.

For Example:

1. I have a list which consists of 10 items. I need to split the list into two equal parts(each with 5 items)
2. I have a list which consists of 9 items sometimes. I need to split the list into two parts(one with 5 items and other with 4 items)

Please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list1 = originalList.Take((int)originalList.Count()/2);
var list2 = originalList.Skip(list1.Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Skip and Take

```
int firstPartCount = originalList.Count() / 2;

var firstPart = originalList.Take(firstPartCount);
var secondPart = originalList.Skip(secondPartCount);
```